# Find out length of the longest entry in a column of a table

Tags: mysql, optimization, phpmyadmin

i have a large size table and there are columns which is bad defined at design. they use char 255 for a columns for urls, now i want to optimize the table by changing the length of these columns.

The problem is that i don't know what is the longest data in these columns to set the length by that to be sure i don't miss any data.

1- Is there any way to find the size of longest entry in this columns?

2- Is there a safe way to optimize my table using PHPMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding length of column data you have to use mysql `LENGTH` function like

```
SELECT length(column_name) FROM `table_name`
```

Comment: good way that i tested but there is something wrong with this, i set the maximum length 255 and there are rows with length of 307. why? maybe because of utf-8 charset?

Comment: I don't know how happen this but mysql automatic truncate when length greater then specified length.

Comment: I either tested with php strlen(), it is because of utf-8, when you retrieve the length of a utf-8 string with none English chars in php or mysql, every char is 2 unit length. but max length of column use the actual char count. so when length (of utf8 column type) is 307 (there are English chars in it) it may be about 150 characters.

Comment: mysql length function return number of character stored in column. Not maximum number of character

Answer (score 0):

From the Structure tab, look for the link "Propose table structure" -- it's under the list of columns and above the area to add new columns:

[image: Location of Propose table structure link]

Clicking that link gives you a page with a bunch of statistics on your table structure and row content, as well as suggestions for the best data type for each column (note that these are just suggestions and aren't always the best choice; for instance I have a table with an auto increment column but only five rows. It suggests that I use ENUM('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') which is silly).

Anyway, this is what the result page looks like:
[image: Propose table structure output]